# Dynamic webpage content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a website with a jQuery UI navigation, and I've got ajax working to dynamically change content between html files. I'm basically just replacing the contents of certain div ids with the contents of other div ids. 
This still requires numerous HTML files and I was wondering if there was a way to have a single html file and load content into the main page from it instead? What about an xml file?

Thanks for the tips and advice about best practices and possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Using HTML:**

Template Views-- Using this method you create separate html files for each piece of your site that you want to be able to load dynamically. This is More efficient, but it means you need to be able to manage your files properly.

Single View-- This method involves loading the entire page again, and extracting out the desired data in order to update the page. This is not very elegant or efficient, and I don't recommend it.

**Using XML/JSON**

This usually involves making ajax requests for data and using it to render the page on the client.

XML/JSON is typically more lightweight than html markup which decreases the amount of cpu time and bandwidth used on your server, however it does require that your users have computers that can handle doing some DOM manipulation.

This also requires that you have a good way of organizing your ajax modules. A pattern that I use looks like this.

$PROJ_DIR/ajax/{MODULENAME}.php

Then a module with the name calendar might accept an actions like, getYears, getTerms, setCurrTerm.

And within that script you switch thought the action to output the correct data, and or make the correct DB changes.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple html files for views isn't a bad thing if you've structured it nicely.

Comment: That might be a better comment than answer. Anyway, that's good to know, but I am really just lazy and would rather go to a single file to make all the changes to content at once.